# iOS sms:// to multiple contact phones

Tags: ios, sms

Does anyone know if it's possible to send a SMS to multiple contact phones by using the **sms://** scheme? On Android the intent runs fine by specifying multiple contact phones.

Comment: If it's with Cocoa (not a web thing for example), you may look at `MFMessageComposeViewController`. But since you didn't said what's the language used...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, sms scheme does not support multiple endpoints:

`parameter can contain the digits 0 through 9 and the plus (+), hyphen (-), and period (.) characters`

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/SMSLinks/SMSLinks.html